# Sparse constrained linear least-squares solver

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, linear-programming, sparse-matrix

[This great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242190/c-memory-efficient-solution-for-axb-linear-algebra-system/1279744#1279744) points to a good sparse solver for `Ax=b`, but I've got constraints on `x` such that each element in `x` is `>=0` an `<=N`.

Also, `A` is *huge* (around 2e6x2e6) but very sparse with `<=4` elements per row.

Any ideas/recommendations? I'm looking for something like MATLAB's [`lsqlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) but with huge sparse matrices.

I'm essentially trying to solve the large scale [bounded variable least squares problem](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/stark/Preprints/bvls.pdf) on sparse matrices:

[image]

**EDIT:**
In [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/):

```
cvx_begin
    variable x(n)
    minimize( norm(A*x-b) );
    subject to 
        x <= N;
        x >= 0;
cvx_end
```

Comment: So what's wrong with using that particular solution? Is it not performant, or are you looking for things to keep in mind before implementing the solution?

Comment: I would like to enforce those constraints I mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps _I_ don't understand the problem, are the constraints not enforcable in that system? Which part shows a problem? Where do you think the constraints should be enforced at? It seems like the solver is implemented in BOOST, which means you would really be focusing on coming up with an altered BOOST library, no? Sorry, I know I'm not helping, but it's an interesting problem.

Comment: No problem. From what I can see, I can't enforce constraints on `x`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I forwarded the link to some other mathy people, maybe they'll be arsed to get online ;) ~ Best of luck...

Comment: Why are you looking at this like a least-squares minimization problem? Isn't this a standard linear programming problem, which you should be able to solve with a simplex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to solve least squares with box constraints. Standard sparse least squares algorithms include LSQR and more recently, LSMR. These only require you to apply matrix-vector products. To add in the constraints, realize that if you are in the interior of the box (none of the constraints are "active"), then you proceed with whatever interior point method you chose. For all active constraints, the next iteration you perform will either deactivate the constraint, or constrain you to move along the constraint hyperplane. With some (conceptually relatively simple) suitable modifications to the algorithm you choose, you can implement these constraints.

Generally however, you can use any convex optimization package. I have personally solved this exact type of problem using the Matlab package CVX, which uses SDPT3/SeDuMi for a backend. CVX is merely a very convenient wrapper around these semidefinite program solvers.

Comment: Yes, I realize it's convex. I've tried CVX but it runs out of memory. Since CVX has been recommended I've posted my CVX solution.

Comment: How large were your matrices?

Comment: I used small dense matrices (about 100x100). You are using the sparse matrices in Matlab right? I believe that you should not run out of memory if you use spconvert() to construct the matrix.

Comment: Yes but some MATLAB functions does not support sparse matrices. CVX also seems to fail for such matrices as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is similar to a **nonnegative least-squares** problem (NNLS), which can be formulated as

$$\min_x ||Ax-b||_2^2 \text{ subject to } x \ge 0$$,

for which there seems to exist many algorithms.

Actually, you problem can be more or less converted into an NNLS problem, if, in addition to your original nonnegative variables $x$ you create additional variables $x'$ and link them with linear constraints $x_i+x_i'=N$. The problem with this approach is that these additional linear constraints might not be satisfied exactly in the least-squares solution - it might be appropriate then to try to weight them with a large number.

Comment: The NNSL problem, which is close but not exactly your problem, can for example be solved using the MATLAB routine lsqnonneg.m

Actually the Optimization Toolbox features the lsqlin.m routine which can solve your problem exactly, and even features a "large-scale algorihm" ; maybe you could test it on your matrix ?

Comment: Other toolboxes worth trying: TSNNLS (Cantarella et al) for NNLS and SLS (by Adlers et al) for your problem

Comment: @Fanfan whether NNLs can use for solving under determined system of equation of the form Ax=B

Comment: @Fanfan I need your guidance to run tsnnls as I am unable to run it using linux. Though it compiles fine, it does not create executable. I have to call using script and I have no idea how does that work. Since I would like to change his code, I would like to have executable being created after compilation rather than calling using some script.

Answer (score 2):

If you reformulate your model as:

min [image]
subject to:
[image]
[image]

then it is a standard quadratic programming problem.  This is a common type of model that can be easily solved with a commercial solver such as CPLEX or Gurobi.  (Disclaimer: I currently work for Gurobi Optimization and formerly worked for ILOG, which provided CPLEX).

Comment: I should add: the y variables aren't strictly necessary.  You could expand the objective and substitute out the y variables.  But adding the y variables makes the model and code easier to write and understand, and they won't make the model harder to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix A^T A is positive semi-definite, so your problem is convex; be sure to take advantage of that when setting up your solver.

Most go-to QP solvers are in Fortran and/or non-free; however I've heard good things about OOQP (http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/otc/Tools/OOQP/OoqpRequestForm.html), though it's a bit of a pain getting a copy.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to solve the quadratic form as well (`quadprog`) but it's too big. I'll take a look at OOQP and hope it works for sparse matrices.

Answer (score 1):

How about CVXOPT? It works with sparse matrices, and it seems that some of the cone programming solvers may help:

http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-cone-programs

This is a simple modification of the code in the doc above, to solve your problem:

```
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers
A = matrix([ [ .3, -.4,  -.2,  -.4,  1.3 ],
             [ .6, 1.2, -1.7,   .3,  -.3 ],
             [-.3,  .0,   .6, -1.2, -2.0 ] ])
b = matrix([ 1.5, .0, -1.2, -.7, .0])
N = 2;
m, n = A.size
I = matrix(0.0, (n,n))
I[::n+1] = 1.0
G = matrix([-I, I])
h = matrix(n*[0.0]  + n*[N])
print G
print h
dims = {'l': n, 'q': [n+1], 's': []}
x = solvers.coneqp(A.T*A, -A.T*b, G, h)['x']#, dims)['x']
print x
```

CVXOPT support sparse matrices, so it be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Matlab, this is something you can do with [TFOCS](http://tfocs.stanford.edu/). This is the syntax you would use to solve the problem:

```
x = tfocs( smooth_quad, { A, -b }, proj_box( 0, N ) );
```

You can pass A as a function handle if it's too big to fit into memory.