# add feature inequality constraints (all xi>0) to an existing solver "minimize{||Ax-b||}"

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra

I have [a library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) that can solve `minimize{||Ax-b||}` (Linear least squares).

- `A` is a matrix, while `x` and `b` is a vector.
- It is possible that `A` is not invertible.
- `A` is not a square matrix.

Now, I want to solve it with additional constraints : `all xi>0`.

### **Question**

How to adapt/encapsulate the solver to support constraints `all xi>0`?

I prefer to think that the existing library is a blackbox function - `solve(A,b,x)`.
 I want to encapsulate it to be `solvePositive(A,b,x)`.

For an answer, I expect rough idea, i.e. it doesn't need to contain any code at all.

**Edit:**  .... or should I write a new algorithm instead?
 If so, what are the names of applicable algorithms?
 I seek for a beginner-friendly guide.

### **My search**

- [An answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011409/sparse-constrained-linear-least-squares-solver) describes something around [LSQR](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsqr/).
- [An answer at math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69613/linear-least-squares-with-inequality-constraints) describes how to do it, but with Lagrangian style.     It is a wonderland for me.
- The 3rd post in [Eigen library's forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=102468) offer a code, but I don't find description how the algorithm works.

Comment: There are plenty of algorithms - and libraries - around to address such problems.  Look up "linear programming".

Comment: @Peter May you be more specific, please?   What are the name of algorithms? Linear programming maximizes/minimizes `Matrix*Vector` rather than minimize `error`.   Can my problem be converted to linear programming?

Comment: Linear programming maximises (or minimises) a cost function.  One of those cost functions can be length of `*Matrix*Vector`.

Comment: @Peter I just searched "linear programming length (or size) vector" find nothing. I read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming ; found only cost similar to `(c^t)*x` (not size). I don't get any sense that cost can be  `||euclidean-size||` e.g. `||A*x-b||`. Please enlighten me.