# Optimize A*x = B solution for a tridiagonal coefficient matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a system of equations in the form of `A*x = B` where `[A]` is a tridiagonal coefficient matrix. Using the Numpy solver `numpy.linalg.solve` I can solve the system of equations for x.

See example below of how I develop the tridiagonal `[A]` martix. the `{B}` vector, and solve for `x`:

```
# Solve system of equations with a tridiagonal coefficient matrix
# uses numpy.linalg.solve

# use Python 3 print function
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

# modules
import numpy as np
import time

ti = time.clock()

#---- Build [A] array and {B} column vector

m = 1000   # size of array, make this 8000 to see time benefits

A = np.zeros((m, m))     # pre-allocate [A] array
B = np.zeros((m, 1))     # pre-allocate {B} column vector

A[0, 0] = 1
A[0, 1] = 2
B[0, 0] = 1

for i in range(1, m-1):
    A[i, i-1] = 7   # node-1
    A[i, i] = 8     # node
    A[i, i+1] = 9   # node+1
    B[i, 0] = 2

A[m-1, m-2] = 3
A[m-1, m-1] = 4
B[m-1, 0] = 3

print('A \n', A)
print('B \n', B)

#---- Solve using numpy.linalg.solve

x = np.linalg.solve(A, B)     # solve A*x = B for x

print('x \n', x)

#---- Elapsed time for each approach

print('NUMPY time', time.clock()-ti, 'seconds')
```

So my question relates to two sections of the above example:

1. Since I am dealing with a tridiagonal matrix for `[A]`, also called a banded matrix, is there a more efficient way to solve the system of equations instead of using `numpy.linalg.solve`?
2. Also, is there a better way to create the tridiagonal matrix instead of using a `for-loop`?

The above example runs on Linux in about `0.08 seconds` according to the `time.clock()` function.

The `numpy.linalg.solve` function works fine, but I'm trying to find an approach that takes advantage of the tridiagonal form of `[A]` in hopes of speeding up the solution even further and then apply that approach to a more complicated example.

Comment: You mean like scipy.linalg.solve_banded()?

Comment: @CraigJCopi The `scipy.linalg.solve_banded()` requires the LU tuple. Would calculating the LU tuple then solving with solve_banded be any faster?

Comment: You can use the Thomas algorithm here, which might be faster. Wikipedia has an implementation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm#Python

Comment: @Gavin Calculate LU tuple? You mean the two integers specifying the number of upper and lower diagonals?  For a tridiagonal matrix this is (1,1).

Comment: @CraigJCopi I tried `sp.solve_banded((1, 1), A, B)` but it does not work, I get an error for number of lower and upper diagonals

Comment: @Gavin A minimal working example isn't provided, but when I make up numbers for all the parameters it works fine for me.  My guess is that you have not correctly constructed the array called ab in the documentation.  It should be a 3xm array, each row is a band.  The documentation describes the structure.

Comment: @CraigJCopi Yeah I saw the `ab` array information. Is there a function that I can use to reshape the `A` matrix into the form required by `ab` ? Consider submitting an answer so we don't add too many comments.

Comment: @Gavin I would construct the bands as needed instead of constructing the full matrix and pulling it apart.  If m is large the full matrix wastes a lot of space.  That being said, if you have the full matrix diag() can pull out the diagonal (by default) and the bands above and below.

Comment: @CraigJCopi I updated my question with a better example and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two immediate performance improvements (1) do not use a loop, (2) use `scipy.linalg.solve_banded()`.

I would write the code something more like

```
import scipy.linalg as la

# Create arrays and set values
ab = np.zeros((3,m))
b = 2*ones(m)
ab[0] = 9
ab[1] = 8
ab[2] = 7

# Fix end points
ab[0,1] = 2
ab[1,0] = 1
ab[1,-1] = 4
ab[2,-2] = 3
b[0] = 1
b[-1] = 3

return la.solve_banded ((1,1),ab,b)
```

There may be more elegant ways to construct the matrix, but this works.

Using `%timeit` in `ipython` the original code took 112 ms for m=1000.  This code takes 2.94 ms for m=10,000, an order of magnitude larger problem yet still almost two orders of magnitude faster!  I did not have the patience to wait on the original code for m=10,000.  Most of the time in the original may be in constructing the array, I did not test this.  Regardless, for large arrays it is much more efficient to only store the non-zero values of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `scipy.sparse` matrix type called `scipy.sparse.dia_matrix` which captures the structure of your matrix well (it will store 3 arrays, in "positions" 0 (diagonal), 1 (above) and -1 (below)). Using this type of matrix you can try `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr` for solving. If your problem has an exact solution, it will be found, otherwise it will find the solution in least squares sense.

```
from scipy import sparse
A_sparse = sparse.dia_matrix(A)
ret_values = sparse.linalg.lsqr(A_sparse, C)
x = ret_values[0]
```

However, this may not be completely optimal in terms of exploiting the triadiagonal structure, there may be a theoretical way of making this faster. What this conversion does do for you is cut down the matrix multiplication expenses to the essential: Only the 3 bands are used. This, in combination with the iterative solver `lsqr` should already yield a speedup.

**Note**: I am not proposing `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`, because it converts your matrix to `csr` format. However, replacing `lsqr` with `spsolve` is worth a try, especially because `spsolve` can bind `UMFPACK`, see relevant [doc on `spsolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html). Also, it may be of interest to  take a look at [this stackoverflow question and answer relating to UMFPACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242190/c-memory-efficient-solution-for-ax-b-linear-algebra-system)

Comment: I cannot find the module `scipy.sparse.lsqr`.  Did you mean `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr` ?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course, it is `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr`. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the input. (edited)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up -- I extended my note, adding a reference to `UMFPACK`. While this is a more general library, it separates optimization into 1) a reorganization of the matrix 2) the actual solving. If there is a way of making it understand that the matrix structure is always the same using scipy commands, then this may attain the performance of dedicated tridiagonal solvers. Otherwise a dedicated banded solver is probably the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You could use [scipy.linalg.solveh_banded](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solveh_banded.html#scipy.linalg.solveh_banded).

**EDIT**: You **CANNOT** used the above as your matrix is not symmetric and I thought it was. However, as was mentioned above in the comment, the Thomas algorithm is great for this

```
a =       [7] * ( m - 2 ) + [3]
b = [1] + [8] * ( m - 2 ) + [4]
c = [2] + [9] * ( m - 2 )
d = [1] + [2] * ( m - 2 ) + [3]

# This is taken directly from the Wikipedia page also cited above
# this overwrites b and d
def TDMASolve(a, b, c, d):
    n = len(d) # n is the numbers of rows, a and c has length n-1
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        d[i+1] -= 1. * d[i] * a[i] / b[i]
        b[i+1] -= 1. * c[i] * a[i] / b[i]
    for i in reversed(xrange(n-1)):
        d[i] -= d[i+1] * c[i] / b[i+1]
    return [d[i] / b[i] for i in xrange(n)]
```

This code is not optimize nor does it use `np`, but if I (or any of the other fine folks here) have time, I will edit it so that it does those thing. It currently times at ~10 ms for m=10000.

Answer (score 0):

This probably will help
There is a function creates_tridiagonal which will create tridiagonal matrix. There is another function which converts a matrix into diagonal ordered form as requested by SciPy solve_banded function.

```
import numpy as np    

def lu_decomp3(a):
    """
    c,d,e = lu_decomp3(a).
    LU decomposition of tridiagonal matrix a = [c\d\e]. On output
    {c},{d} and {e} are the diagonals of the decomposed matrix a.
    """
    n = np.diagonal(a).size
    assert(np.all(a.shape ==(n,n))) # check if square matrix

    d = np.copy(np.diagonal(a)) # without copy (assignment destination is read-only) error is raised 
    e = np.copy(np.diagonal(a, 1))
    c = np.copy(np.diagonal(a, -1)) 

    for k in range(1,n):
        lam = c[k-1]/d[k-1]
        d[k] = d[k] - lam*e[k-1]
        c[k-1] = lam
    return c,d,e

def lu_solve3(c,d,e,b):
    """
    x = lu_solve(c,d,e,b).
    Solves [c\d\e]{x} = {b}, where {c}, {d} and {e} are the
    vectors returned from lu_decomp3.
    """
    n = len(d)
    y = np.zeros_like(b)

    y[0] = b[0]
    for k in range(1,n): 
        y[k] = b[k] - c[k-1]*y[k-1]

    x = np.zeros_like(b)
    x[n-1] = y[n-1]/d[n-1] # there is no x[n] out of range
    for k in range(n-2,-1,-1):
        x[k] = (y[k] - e[k]*x[k+1])/d[k]
    return x

from scipy.sparse import diags
def create_tridiagonal(size = 4):
    diag = np.random.randn(size)*100
    diag_pos1 = np.random.randn(size-1)*10
    diag_neg1 = np.random.randn(size-1)*10

    a = diags([diag_neg1, diag, diag_pos1], offsets=[-1, 0, 1],shape=(size,size)).todense()
    return a

a = create_tridiagonal(4)
b = np.random.randn(4)*10

print('matrix a is\n = {} \n\n and vector b is \n {}'.format(a, b))

c, d, e = lu_decomp3(a)
x = lu_solve3(c, d, e, b)

print("x from our function is {}".format(x))

print("check is answer correct ({})".format(np.allclose(np.dot(a, x), b)))


## Test Scipy
from scipy.linalg import solve_banded

def diagonal_form(a, upper = 1, lower= 1):
    """
    a is a numpy square matrix
    this function converts a square matrix to diagonal ordered form
    returned matrix in ab shape which can be used directly for scipy.linalg.solve_banded
    """
    n = a.shape[1]
    assert(np.all(a.shape ==(n,n)))

    ab = np.zeros((2*n-1, n))

    for i in range(n):
        ab[i,(n-1)-i:] = np.diagonal(a,(n-1)-i)

    for i in range(n-1): 
        ab[(2*n-2)-i,:i+1] = np.diagonal(a,i-(n-1))


    mid_row_inx = int(ab.shape[0]/2)
    upper_rows = [mid_row_inx - i for i in range(1, upper+1)]
    upper_rows.reverse()
    upper_rows.append(mid_row_inx)
    lower_rows = [mid_row_inx + i for i in range(1, lower+1)]
    keep_rows = upper_rows+lower_rows
    ab = ab[keep_rows,:]


    return ab

ab = diagonal_form(a, upper=1, lower=1) # for tridiagonal matrix upper and lower = 1

x_sp = solve_banded((1,1), ab, b)
print("is our answer the same as scipy answer ({})".format(np.allclose(x, x_sp)))
```